# How to take sum of product of the following function?

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, karnaugh-map

I'm trying to find the sum of products of the following function using `K-Map`:

```
F(A,B,C,D) = m(0, 1, 5, 7, 8, 10, 14, 15)
```

Since the function is already in sum of products form, what I am trying to do is simply mark '1' on the `K-map` on the boxes of values given in the function, and then simplify it.

Here's what I am getting in the result:

```
B'C'D' + AC'D + B'CD + A'CD'
```

But in the book, the answer is written something like this:

```
AC'D' + BC'D + A'CD + B'CD'
```

OR

```
AB'D' + ABC' + A'BD + A'B'C
```

I don't know where I am getting it wrong?

Comment: You probably either have a _typo_ in the expression `F(A,B,C,D) = m(0, 1, 5, 7, 8, 10, 14, 15)`, because both the answers (boolean expressions), that you copied from your book, match `F(A,B,C,D) = ∑(2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13)` (minterms on that indexes), OR you might have _mismatched_ the function and its supposed solution. Could you please check that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, that the function F(A,B,C,D) = m(0, 1, 5, 7, 8, 10, 14, 15) translates to this **truth-table** (and there are no *"don't care"* states):

```
 index | ABCD | output
----------------------------------------
     0 | 0000 | 1 ... m_0 = ¬A·¬B·¬C·¬D
     1 | 0001 | 1 ... m_1 = ¬A·¬B·¬C·D
     2 | 0010 | 0     M_2 = A + B + ¬C + D
     3 | 0011 | 0     M_3 = A + B + ¬C + ¬D
     4 | 0100 | 0     M_4 = A + ¬B + C + D
     5 | 0101 | 1 ... m_5 = ¬A·B·¬C·D
     6 | 0110 | 0     M_6 = A + ¬B + ¬C + D
     7 | 0111 | 1 ... m_7 = ¬A·B·C·D
     8 | 1000 | 1 ... m_8 = A·¬B·¬C·¬D
     9 | 1001 | 0     M_9 = ¬A + B + C + ¬D
    10 | 1010 | 1 ... m_10 = A·¬B·C·¬D
    11 | 1011 | 0     M_11 = ¬A + B + ¬C + ¬D
    12 | 1100 | 0     M_12 = ¬A + ¬B + C + D
    13 | 1101 | 0     M_13 = ¬A + ¬B + C + ¬D
    14 | 1110 | 1 ... m_14 = A·B·C·¬D
    15 | 1111 | 1 ... m_15 = A·B·C·D
```

the corresponding **sum of minterms (canonical DNF)** looks like this:

```
F(A,B,C,D) = ∑(m_0, m_1, m_5, m_7, m_8, m_10, m_14, m_15) = 
           = m_0 + m_1 + m_5 + m_7 + m_8 + m_10 + m_14 + m_15 =
           = ¬A·¬B·¬C·¬D + ¬A·¬B·¬C·D + ¬A·B·¬C·D + ¬A·B·C·D + 
             + A·¬B·¬C·¬D + A·¬B·C·¬D + A·B·C·¬D + A·B·C·D .
```

[image: Corresponding K-maps]

You can see all the minterms of the canonical (complete) DNF (circled separately) in **the first Karnaugh map**:

```
m_0  = ¬A·¬B·¬C·¬D (blue)
m_1  = ¬A·¬B·¬C·D (purple)
m_5  = ¬A·B·¬C·D (green)
m_7  = ¬A·B·C·D (orange)
m_8  = A·¬B·¬C·¬D (black)
m_10 = A·¬B·C·¬D (yellow)
m_14 = A·B·C·¬D (brown)
m_15 = A·B·C·D (pink)
```

**The second K-map** shows the minimal DNF to the original function:

```
F(A,B,C,D) = ¬A·¬B·¬C (blue) + ¬A·B·D (purple) + A·¬B·¬D (orange) + A·B·C (green)
```

and **the third K-map** also a minimal DNF, but different to the prior expression:

```
F(A,B,C,D) = ¬B·¬C·¬D (orange) + ¬A·¬C·D (blue) + A·C·¬D (green) + B·C·D (purple)
```

You could also use the **maxterms** to express the original output function as their product. That will be the canonical CNF:

```
F(A,B,C,D) = ∏(M_2, M_3, M_4, M_6, M_9, M_11, M_12, M_13) = 
           = M_2·M_3·M_4·M_6·M_9·M_11·M_12·M_13 =
           = (A + B + ¬C + D)·(A + B + ¬C + ¬D)·(A + ¬B + C + D)·
            ·(A + ¬B + ¬C + D)·(¬A + B + C + ¬D)·(¬A + B + ¬C + ¬D)·
            ·(¬A + ¬B + C + D)·(¬A + ¬B + C + ¬D) .
```

[image: CNFs in K-maps]

**The first K-map of the second picture** shows all the maxterms of the original function circled separately:

```
M_2 = A + B + ¬C + D (purple)
M_3 = A + B + ¬C + ¬D (green)
M_4 = A + ¬B + C + D (blue)
M_6 = A + ¬B + ¬C + D (orange)
M_9 = ¬A + B + C + ¬D (pink)
M_11 = ¬A + B + ¬C + ¬D (yellow)
M_12 = ¬A + ¬B + C + D (black)
M_13 = ¬A + ¬B + C + ¬D (brown)
```

**The second and third K-maps of the second picture** both show the minimal CNFs (there can be more than one) of the original function:

```
F(A,B,C,D) = (A + B + ¬C) ... blue
            ·(A + ¬B + D) ... purple
            ·(¬A + B + ¬D) ... orange
            ·(¬A + ¬B + C) ... green

F(A,B,C,D) = (¬B + C + D) ... orange 
            ·(A + ¬C + D) ... green
            ·(B + ¬C + ¬D) ... purple
            ·(¬A + C + ¬D) ... blue
```

Comment on my answer, please, if you have any additional questions.

The pictures were generated using latex.